# mathematica exponential Nth derivative treated as an unknown function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to create a list of Hankel functions, defined in terms of an Nth derivative, but the Nth order derivatives get treated in the way that is described in the docs under "Derivatives of unknown functions", and left unevaluated.  Here's an example:

```
Clear[x, gaussianExponential]
gaussianExponential[x_] := Exp[- x^2]
FullSimplify[Derivative[2][gaussianExponential[x]]]
```

I get:
    (E^-x^2)^[Prime][Prime]

(instead of seeing the derivatives evaluated (and the final expressions are left unsimplified)).

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Derivative` applies to the function symbol `f`, not to the function evaluated at a point `f[x]`. So what you want is

```
Clear[x, gaussianExponential]
gaussianExponential[x_] := Exp[-x^2]
Derivative[2][gaussianExponential][x]//FullSimplify
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is:

```
Clear[x, gaussianExponential]
gaussianExponential[x_] := Exp[-x^2]
FullSimplify[Derivative[2][gaussianExponential][x]]
```

Comment: Only out by 4 seconds - should we call it a draw?

Comment: @Simon My apologies, but in my new ultra-tachy-neutrino-2011 turbo machine, I can distinctly see my answer was first.

Comment: @Simon, pistols? Calculators!

Comment: @rcollyer Calculators are for cowards! This is my proposal. http://www.gilai.com/product_428/Mannheim-Slide-Rule-Made-in-1920-by-Albert-Nestler-No.9--.

Comment: @Simon, I'll witness the duel by weapons of choice in this [room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/4054/duel-at-dawn?tab=general), at dawn (defined as whenever we can agree it is).

Comment: Wow... this duel thing got serious very quickly... Now I know how Galois felt!

Comment: I just viewed the duel room.  Hilarious!