# Constrained Random Number Generation

Tags: random, wolfram-mathematica

I need to generate 500 numbers, 250 1s and 250 0s, randomly located. Below is what I do now. But it does not feel right while the output is correct.

```
trialNo=500

RandomSample@Flatten[Table[#, {trialNo/2}] & /@ {0, 1}]
```

Comment: Actually, this seems an optimal way to do it (to me anyway), nothing wrong with it

Comment: You might be interested in this recent Wolfram Research Q&A item on random number generation: http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/10/05/mathematica-qa-series-generating-random-numbers/

Comment: @Leonid, I am sincerely taking that as an important step on my Mathematica journey ;-)

Comment: I agree with Leonid that it is quite fine as is. All the same, here is a reasonable alternative. Clip[RandomSample[Range[trialNo]], {trialNo,trialNo}/2 + .5, {0,1}]

Comment: Since your method works fine as written, submit an answer to that effect, and accept it.

Comment: @rcollyer, I believe you provided a great answer that helped me understand what I was doing myself.

Comment: Truthfully, when I wrote the answer, I was thinking about six months from now when you dust off this code and try to figure out what it does. A LOT, of my old code is incomprehensible at first (third, twelfth) look at it, so I add lots of comments and break out some steps where I can.

Comment: 500, if you are still using this method please see my updated answer.  It's much cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd actually do something slightly different. Since you're looking for a random permutation of `Flatten[{ConstantArray[0,250], ConstantArray[1,250]}]`, I'd generate the permutation and use `Part` to get the list you're looking for.  As follows,

```
perm = RandomSample[Range[trialNo]];
Flatten[{ConstantArray[0, trialNo/2], ConstantArray[1, trialNo/2]}][[ perm ]]
```

This isn't operationally different than what you're doing, but I think it captures mathematically what your trying to accomplish better.

Comment: you beat me to it by 10 seconds!

Comment: I actually found that the original OP's code is totally all right, so I deleted my answer (looks like it is becoming a habit)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, his answer definitely works. I just thought it could be mathematically clearer, if not programmaticly distinctive.

Comment: @rcollyer Perhaps so. I somehow first thought that the original code did not work at all, and realized the opposite already after having posted my answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd, it shames me that as a native speaker, I failed at the "your / you're" test.

Comment: @yoda, careful. I don't know if you saw what [happened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669498/mathematica-exponential-nth-derivative-treated-as-an-unknown-function/7669632#comment9321401_7669632) the last time this occurred. It can seriously change a person.

Comment: @rcollyer Happens to me all the time. Often when I'm not looking at the output my fingers autonomously decide to start typing phonetically.

Comment: @yoda, oh, and I just eclipsed you, again, in the rankings ... :)

Comment: @rcollyer lol! The room is hilarious. I was following that up until then, but didn't notice that it had gone over and beyond!

Comment: @rcollyer I see you've been following it as closely as I have... I'm at 235 now to your 234 :D I wouldn't be surprised if you overtake me though... I've greatly reduced my time on [so] these days

Comment: Hmmm... you caught up just as I finished typing my comment. Not cool `<{~.~}>`. Must commence operation "Revoke Upvotes".

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do this.

```
Round[Ordering[1~RandomReal~#] / N@#]& @ 500
```

Now with more magic for [the guys in Chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2088439#2088439)

```
Mod[RandomSample@Range@#, 2] & @ 500
```

Comment: Thank You, hope you are well ! not seen you around in a while !

Comment: @500, you are welcome, and thank you, I am fine, just busy with other things these days.  Your own code for this problem is very nice, and I don't see any reason to change it.  This is merely something else to learn from, which you appear to do quite well.

Comment: Okay, you win. A very clever way of generating a random permutation, and guaranteed to have an equal number of 0s and 1s.

Comment: You already got a +1 from me. You're just trying to get more points! :)